# react-hook-form handling server-side errors in handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to handle errors that don't necessarily pertain to a single input field in a `react-hook-form`.
To put it differently, how do I handle `handleSubmit` errors?

For example, having the following form:

```
import to from 'await-to-js'
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'
import React from "react"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"

type LoginFormData = {
  username: string,
  password: string,
}

export const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<LoginFormData>()

  const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    const url = '/auth/local'

    const [err, userLoginResult] = await to<AxiosResponse>(axios.post(url, data))
    if (userLoginResult) {
      alert('Login successful')
    }
    else if (err) {
      alert('Bad username or password')
    }
  })

  return (
    <div className="RegisterOrLogIn">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="username">username</label>
          <input name="username" id="username" ref={register} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" ref={register} />
        </div>
        <button type="submit"> </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Is there a `react-hook-form` way of informing the user that there's an error with either the username or the password?**
as in, other than `alert()`

Perhaps this is answered elsewhere, but I could not find it.

---

**Clarification**
The error received from the server does not pertain to a single field:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": [
        {
            "messages": [
                {
                    "id": "Auth.form.error.invalid",
                    "message": "Identifier or password invalid."
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "messages": [
                {
                    "id": "Auth.form.error.invalid",
                    "message": "Identifier or password invalid."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In order to display the error from the server to your user, you need to use:

- [`setError`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/seterror/#main) to set the error programmatically when the server returns an error response.
- [`errors`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate#:%7E:text=true%20during%20validation.-,errors,-object) to get the error state of every fields in your form to display to the user.

```js
type FormInputs = {
  username: string;
};

const { setError, formState: { errors } } = useForm<FormInputs>();
```

**In your `handleSubmit` callback**

```js
axios
  .post(url, data)
  .then((response) => {
    alert("Login successful");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    const errors = e.response.data;

    if (errors.username) {
      setError('username', {
        type: "server",
        message: 'Something went wrong with username',
      });
    }
    if (errors.password) {
      setError('password', {
        type: "server",
        message: 'Something went wrong with password',
      });
    }
  });
```

**In your component**

```js
<label htmlFor="username">username</label>
<input id="username" {...register("username")} />
<div>{errors.username && errors.username.message}</div>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64469861/react-hook-form-handling-errors-in-handlesubmit]

Comment: this only handle if there is any wrong with username or password but what about api timeout error

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by @NearHuscarl's answer, I've done the following hack s.t. changes in either the `username` or the `password` inputs will remove the single error.

This hack does not scale well if your error is related to multiple fields in the form, but it worked for the login use case.

onSubmit:

```
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    const url = '/auth/local'

    const [err, userLoginResult] = await to<AxiosResponse>(axios.post(url, data)) // see await-to-js 
    if (userLoginResult) {
      alert('Login successful')
    }
    else if (err) {
      const formError = { type: "server", message: "Username or Password Incorrect" }
      // set same error in both:
      setError('password', formError)
      setError('username', formError)
    }
  })
```

component:

```
  return (
    <div className="RegisterOrLogIn">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="username">username</label>
          <input name="username" id="username" ref={register} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" ref={register} />
        </div>
        <div>{errors.username && errors.password?.message /*note the cross check*/}</div>
        <button type="submit"> </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
```

by setting and rendering the error on both `errors.password` & `errors.username`, the error will disappear when the user updates either of those fields.

Comment: You can remove the if-else branch in the error handling by standardizing the error messages returned from the server. You're not supposed to set the error manually for every fields. See the live demo in my answer for more detail.

Comment: @NearHuscarl - not sure what you mean, but the `if(successCaseResult){success handle} else if(error){error handle}` is an error handling pattern of `await`ed calls. [See here for more info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-to-js)

Answer (score 2):

Since v7.43.0, you can use the syntax `root.xxx` error to handle server error or some global level error.

```
const onSubmit = () => {
  try {
    fetch(...)
    if (response.statusCode > 300) {
        setError('root.serverError', { 
          type: response.statusCode,
          message: e.message,
          // meta: {}, // something to be consider to included in the phase 2 with meta object
        })
    }
  } catch(e) {
    setError('root.serverCatch', { 
      type: 'server',
      message: e.message
    })
  }
}

const onClick = () => {
  setError('root.random', { 
    type: 'random', 
    message: 'random' 
  })
}

return (
  <>
    {errors.root.serverError.type === 400 && <p>server response message</p>}
    <p>{errors.root.serverError.message}</p>
    
    {errors.root.serverCatch.type === 'server' && <p>server error message</p>}
    <p>{errors.root.serverCatch.message}</p>
    
    <p>{errors.root.random.message}</p>
  </>
)
```

[RFC](https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/9691)